# c# not to call editValueChanged on form load

Tags: c#, devexpress, edit

Due to fact that I load data from a database and place it into a DevExpress TextEdit control on FormLoad, the event handler TextEdit_EditValueChanged is called. Is it possible to make any checking in the event handler, or prevent the event from being raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
bool dataLoaded = false;

private void LoadData()
{
    // do the loading and set the Text property of the textEdit
    dataLoaded = true;
}

private void TextEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataLoaded == false) return;
    // the code after this comment will run only after the data was loaded
}
```

Or you can add the event handler after the loading was done, like this:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    // do the loading and set the Text property of the textEdit
    TextEdit.EditValueChanged += TextEdit_EditValueChanged;
}

private void TextEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the code after this comment will run only after the data was loaded
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use property

```
private void TextEdit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsLoaded) return;
    // the code after this comment will run only after the data was loaded
}
```